# Getting JS error: "Cannot call a class as a function"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

I had an existing working react code written in Typescript (and hence ES6) using [react-vis](https://github.com/uber/react-vis) library. The library itself [seem to use ES6](https://github.com/uber/react-vis/blob/cacb3ca24138e9960caa2a4687505af8995f69ec/package.json#L34).

Now I have another version of this react app which is written in older react version (using django templates, no TypeScript and no ES6). Now, I want to replicate the react-vis code in this older version of react app.

While doing so I face following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call a class as a function
    at _classCallCheck (dist.min.js:formatted:23789:27)
    at LabelSeries (dist.min.js:formatted:23823:21)
    at Constructor.render (<anonymous>:1866:23)
    at Constructor.<anonymous> (react.js:6029:34)
    at Constructor._renderValidatedComponent (react.js:11403:21)
    at Constructor.<anonymous> (react.js:5582:14)
    at Constructor.mountComponent (react.js:11403:21)
    at Constructor.mountChildren (react.js:10913:42)
    at Constructor._createContentMarkup (react.js:6812:32)
    at Constructor.<anonymous> (react.js:6734:14)
```

I debugged both the versions of the react apps as below:

[image]

Left side shows debug sessions of old react app, while right side shows debug sessions of new react app. Blue lines and arrows shows function call sequence. Its same in both apps, so shown in only on left. Pink text mentions frames in stack trace above. I have shown only top three stack frames as its related to `react-vis` library. Green boxes show variables having same values in debug sessions in corresponding stack frames of both apps. Red boxes show variables having different values.

As can be seen in first stack frame `<anonymous>:1866:23`, I am passing same property values to `<LabelSeries>` component of `react-vis` library in both new and old react app. The issue seems to be in the next stack frame (`dist.min.js:formatted:23823:21`) where old react app have `this = undefined`, whereas new react app have `this = LabelSeries`.

As I said, new react app is based on TypeScript, so it supports ES6, but that is not the case with old react app. Also the `react-vis` library itself [seem to use ES6](https://github.com/uber/react-vis/blob/cacb3ca24138e9960caa2a4687505af8995f69ec/package.json#L34). Are these ES versions causing issue? If yes, what is the exact reason? (Not a seasoned JS / ES developer ...)  And how do I fix it?

**PS:** [Here](https://gist.github.com/RajS999/62bfb43b8dbda878545e8e9b7d8e5826#file-react-vis-dist-js-L23789) is the this prettified version `dist.min.js` from my chrome browser for reference. (Note that github gist does not render full file. You have to click [view full file to get raw version](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/RajS999/62bfb43b8dbda878545e8e9b7d8e5826/raw/43ef5ecfe8024aaba41d78d652e3d339878fcbaa/react-vis.dist.js)). And here is [`unpkg` version of react-vis `dist.min.js`](https://unpkg.com/browse/react-vis@1.11.7/dist/dist.min.js).

Comment: It's probably that your project is set to target ES5 or earlier and is extending a class it gets from something targeting ES2015 or later. Please show the `tsconfig.json` of your project.

Comment: Yeah I reckon that, but this old react app is django-template app and is not developed in TypeScript and probably in ES5 or earlier. So it does not have `tsconfig.json`. [Here](https://gist.github.com/RajS999/d6c43e843d41ef1575a561313714f86a) is tsconfig of new react app. Also I see that this tsconfig has `target:ES5`.

Comment: Please don't just post links.  The way SO works, your whole question (including any necessary code) has to be **in** your question, not just linked. Three reasons: People shouldn't have to go off-site to help you; some sites are blocked for some users; and links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future. Put the necessary information **in** the question, as text. For instance: What is the `LabelSeries` code that's failing?

Comment: Basically: It sounds like you have some TypeScript that's doing `class X extends Y` and targeting ES5, but `Y` isn't ES5, it's an ES2015+ `class` constructor. When you do that, TypeScript converts `X` into a traditional function and converts the `super()` call into `Y.call(this)` (or similar). You can't do that with an ES2015+ `class` constructor. So you'll have to track down what's doing that and, if you need ES5 output, ensure that all of the necessary code is ES5-compatible (either written using ES5-level feature sonly, or compiled targeting ES5).

Comment: React-vis library seem to use ES6 and has [`class LabelSeries extends AbstractSeries`](https://github.com/uber/react-vis/blob/cacb3ca24138e9960caa2a4687505af8995f69ec/packages/react-vis/src/plot/series/label-series.js#L42). New React based app has `"target":"es5"`, but it is not extending any class from react-vis library.  Then why it is working in new react based app?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I realized that the issue is that my project is in ES5 and I am trying to use `react-vis` library which is in ES6. Can you please tell if recompiling the library down to ES5 will resolve the issue? I was thinking to do ES6 to ES5 conversion using babel as explained [here](https://medium.com/@SunnyB/how-to-convert-es6-into-es5-using-babel-1b533d31a169). Is there any other better solution?