# How to generate single ES5 bundle file from ES6 project using webpack?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I am trying to use [`react-vis`](https://github.com/uber/react-vis) library in my project. In their [readme file](https://github.com/uber/react-vis), they have asked to import library by adding following lines in non-node environment:

> If you're working in a non-node environment, you can also directly include the bundle and compiled style using basic html tags.
>
> ```
> <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/react-vis/dist/style.css">
> <script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/react-vis/dist/dist.min.js"></script>
> ```
>
> The global `reactVis` object will now be available for you to play around.

When I did that, I got following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call a class as a function
    at _classCallCheck (dist.min.js:formatted:23789:27)
    at LabelSeries (dist.min.js:formatted:23823:21)
    at Constructor.render (<anonymous>:1866:23)
    at Constructor.<anonymous> (react.js:6029:34)
    at Constructor._renderValidatedComponent (react.js:11403:21)
    at Constructor.<anonymous> (react.js:5582:14)
    at Constructor.mountComponent (react.js:11403:21)
    at Constructor.mountChildren (react.js:10913:42)
    at Constructor._createContentMarkup (react.js:6812:32)
    at Constructor.<anonymous> (react.js:6734:14)
```

[After a lot of digging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71914546/getting-js-error-cannot-call-a-class-as-a-function?noredirect=1#comment127077693_71914546), I realised the issue was that the react-vis library follows ES6, while my project is in ES5. So, I thought to transpile react-vis library to ES5. I used babel as explained in [this](https://medium.com/@SunnyB/how-to-convert-es6-into-es5-using-babel-1b533d31a169) post to transpile ES6 to ES5 (with [slight changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71940735/how-to-compile-es6-code-to-es5-using-babeljs#comment127122059_71940735)). But, it generated multiple files. I needed single bundle file.

So, I followed steps explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69945841/6357916) to generate single ES5 bundle file. I used same `webpack.config.js` as specified in these steps. And my scripts in `package.json` look something like this:

```
"build:babel": "babel src -d build"
"build:app": "npm run build:babel",
"build:bundle": "webpack --mode production",
"build3": "npm run build:app && npm run build:bundle"
```

It was successful, but when I used generated bundle file, I got error `ReferenceError: reactVis`. When I checked the generated bundle file, it did not contain `reactVis` variable. So, now I have two doubts:

**Q1.** how can I tell webpack to preserve `reactVis` variable?
**Q2.** how can I make webpack to add it to global scope (or how can I access this variable in my project once I linked the generated bundle)?